# PInvokeStackImbalance while using "static extern int system(string str)"

Tags: c#, msvcrt

I'm trying to use the system(string str) Command for dos-operations in C#.

```
namespace XYZ
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
        static extern int system(string str);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             string Command = Console.ReadLine();
             system(Command); 
             /* Excutes command, then "PInvokeStackImbalance". */
        }
    }
}
```

I know using `static extern int system(string str)` is a bad solution, but I've tried other solutions which did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to specify the calling convention:

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int system(string str);
```

I normally try to explain why but that seems unnecessary here ;)  This is otherwise unlikely to fix your problem, whatever it may be, it is the same thing as

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c " + str);
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, you are doing it the wrong way. This function was meant for C/C++ native console-based applications. In C# you have the System.Diagnostic namespace, and you can easily start new processes with it. Please look here: [C++ "system()" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806427/c-system-in-c-sharp)

Of course you **can** use that function, too. The exception is probably called because the DllImport phrase is incomplete, see [in .Net 4: PInvokeStackImbalance Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723021/in-net-4-pinvokestackimbalance-exception) This thread is about strlen, but I'm almost sure that the system() and strlen() use the same stack convention.